# How to send data to ESP8266?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to send data to ESP8266 to work with my motors. I just need send string 00 or 10 or 01 it depends what button I will press. So it have to look like this: http://ipaddress:port/00
So I found this code. I changed it so it can work with my program.
So I install app to my phone and I connect to ESP8266´s hotspot. Then I send(click on button) the value(00 or 10 or 01). The Esp receive this string. BUT when I want click second button(to change string) it WILL NOT send it. The code is stuck and I thing it is waiting for response or something like that. But I don´t want resposne from my Arduino(ESP8266) I just want send datas imadiately...

```
View.OnClickListener btnSetClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String value;
            if (view== btnSet) {
               value = "/10";
            } else if(view == btnMinus) {
                value = "/01";
            } else {
                value = "/00";
            }
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "OnClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String PORT = editPort.getText().toString();
            String serverIP = editIp.getText().toString() + ":" + PORT + value;
            textInfo1.setText(serverIP);

            TaskEsp taskEsp = new TaskEsp(serverIP);
            taskEsp.execute();

private class TaskEsp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String server;

    TaskEsp(String server){
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        final String p = "http://"+server;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textInfo1.setText(p);
            }
        });

        String serverResponse = "";
        String port = null;
        //HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = p;

        try {


            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(p).openConnection());
            if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText("Try");
                }
            });
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                serverResponse = bufferedReader.readLine();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText("return");
            }
        });
        return serverResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        textInfo2.setText(s);
        textView.setText("PostExc");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it fail silently ?

Comment: html: `<button onclick='new Image().src="http://192.168.1.111/?11'>on</button>`

Comment: It doesn´t fail, it just work only once. It´s somewhere stucked

Answer (score 1):

you can use a different approach to this:

1. You can use aRest library. It helps you to expose arduino/ESP functions as API
2. Implement a simple Android app that connects to ESP and sends the required data.

I've made a tutorial explaining how to send data from an android app. You can give a look [here](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/05/arduino-rest-api-iot.html) and [here](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/03/how-to-control-leds-connected-to-arduino-using-androidd-app.html)

If you look for an example how to implement a web server on ESP and implement an Android app to exchange data you can refer to my post [here](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/06/internet-of-things-with-android-and-arduino.html)

Comment: I´m  not sure if I did everything ok, but it is not working to me.

Comment: What kind of error do you have?....Can you tell me what is not working?

Comment: I just need open url in background... If I try open url in browser it is working. But I need open this "url" in app. And this code what I have is working only once. First "url" send/open. I am new in programing in Java...

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the same thing but with different approach,

In this case I am creating a JSON object where I am adding all the click responses as the values to the JSON and this JSON is posted to the web server hosted by ESP8266.

on the ESP side I am parsing this JSON from WebServer and getting the values from it.

I've a similar kind of project where I am controlling the relays from android application You can go to this [LINK](https://github.com/vbshightime/IoTemperature) for detail discription.